# Cutting point in the fastcluster module

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to use Python fastcluster module for hierarchical clustering:

```
linkage = fastcluster.linkage(distance,method="complete")
```

It works fine when I know beforehand the number of clusters. But I can not find the syntax for cutting point in the gained hierarchy. I appreciate any help in this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have first set your criteria. Based on this criteria you can choose cutoff values.
for example:

```
X = np.array([.....])
Y = pdist(X)
Z = linkage(Y)
I = inconsistent(Z)
```

Then based on consistency results select your cutoff point.

```
fcluster(Z,cutoff,criterion='inconsistent')
```

see fcluster documentation for further help